# string remove all letters

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Why this will print the same result?

```
string tester = "stUniqueId01";
Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + tester);
var regex = tester.Replace("[^0-9.]", "");
Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + regex);
```

Output:

```
ID: stUniqueId01
ID: stUniqueId01
```

Comment: Because `String.Replace` does not support regex. Use `var regex = Regex.Replace(tester, "[^0-9.]", "");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling [`string.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I think you want:

```
string tester = "stUniqueId01";
Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + tester);
var regex = new Regex("[^0-9.]");
Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + regex.Replace(tester,""));
```

or:

```
string tester = "stUniqueId01";
Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + tester);
var replaced = Regex.Replace(tester,"[^0-9.]","");
Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + replaced);
```

if you don't intend to reuse the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Replace method from String. It takes strings, not regular expressions. Try:

```
string tester = "stUniqueId01";
Console.WriteLine("ID: " + tester);
Regex rx = new Regex("[^0-9.]");
var regex = rx.Replace(tester, "");
Console.WriteLine("ID: " + regex);
```

Result:

```
ID: stUniqueId01
ID: 01
```